# Mutate group of columns based on values in other group of columns

Tags: r, tidyr, dplyr

I am trying to convert values in one column to `NA` based on if the values in another corresponding column are `NA`. I need to do this for two large groups of corresponding columns so I cannot `mutate` each column one by one.

For example, below, 2002 `inflationNext2Years` turns to `NA` since 2002 `realReturnNext2Years` is `NA`.

```
year <- c(2000, 2001, 2002)
realReturnNext1Years <- c(.1,.2,.3)
realReturnNext2Years <- c(.15,.25, NA)
realReturnNext3Years <- c(.45, NA, NA)
inflationNext1Years <- c(.02, .03, .07)
inflationNext2Years <- c(.03, .05, .08)
inflationNext3Years <- c(.04, .06, .09)
data <- data.frame(year, realReturnNext1Years, realReturnNext2Years, realReturnNext3Years, inflationNext1Years, inflationNext2Years, inflationNext3Years)
data
   year realReturnNext1Years realReturnNext2Years realReturnNext3Years inflationNext1Years inflationNext2Years inflationNext3Years
1 2000                  0.1                 0.15                 0.45                0.02                0.03                0.04
2 2001                  0.2                 0.25                   NA                0.03                0.05                0.06
3 2002                  0.3                   NA                   NA                0.07                0.08                0.09
```

I am trying to covert `data` into:

```
year realReturnNext1Years realReturnNext2Years realReturnNext3Years inflationNext1Years inflationNext2Years inflationNext3Years
2000                  0.1                 0.15                 0.45                0.02                0.03              0.04
2001                  0.2                 0.25                   NA                0.03                0.05              NA
2002                  0.3                   NA                   NA                0.07                NA                NA
```

Since I have many columns, I cannot do this one column at a time. I tried to use `mutate_at` with an `ifelse()` but was not sure how to test if the number of years lined up.

I have a vector of the `realReturn` column names and another vector of the `inflation` column names. I am trying to change the inflation columns to `NA` if their corresponding realReturnColumn is `NA`, but keep the inflation column the same if the realReturnColumn is not `NA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can collect indices of "realReturnNext" columns using `grep`, get the position of their `NA`'s and replace the corresponding positions in "inflationNext" cols to `NA`'s

```
real_cols <- grep("^realReturnNext", colnames(data))
inflation_cols <- grep("^inflationNext", colnames(data))

data[inflation_cols][is.na(data[real_cols])] <- NA

#  year realReturnNext1Years realReturnNext2Years realReturnNext3Years
#1 2000                  0.1                 0.15                 0.45
#2 2001                  0.2                 0.25                   NA
#3 2002                  0.3                   NA                   NA

#  inflationNext1Years inflationNext2Years inflationNext3Years
#1                0.02                0.03                0.04
#2                0.03                0.05                  NA
#3                0.07                  NA                  NA
```